Additional CSS classes not being added in Gutenberg editor
When we add additional classes to our custom block they are not being added in the editor. When we save the block and view the front-end the additional classes are showing. But in the editor they won't show up.
Here is the code of our block:
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';


export default {
    name: 'erik-dekker/button',
    title: 'Knop',
    icon: 'button',
    category: 'erik-dekker',
    edit: () => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps();

        return (
            <div { ...blockProps }>hello world!</div>
        );
    },
    save: () => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();

        return (
            <div { ...blockProps }>hello world!</div>
        );
    }
}

Thanks for your time!
